# Where is the sort ordering algorithm in spark source code?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a simple query:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY age").collect()
```

My question is:

In Spark Source Code, where can I find the ordering comparator between rows, which executes this query?

I already inspect the source code by debugging on IntelliJ and I know that the the physical operator is SortExec, however I don't find any compare or compareTo method.

There is very little documentation to understand the spark code.